# CentOS as a Docker host causes different container behavior compared to any other host OS

Tags: docker, centos, containers, linux-capabilities

I am working with Docker on different Hosts : RHEL7 , SELS12 and CentOS7,
And i found a different behavior in containers which running on CentOS7 as Docker Host, comparing to containers which running on SLES12 or RHEL7 as Docker hosts.

The different behavior is related to those common issues in Docker containers: 
https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/7147
https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/6800

### In container with CentOS7 as Docker host:

I **have a permission** to resolve a symbolic in the path: /proc/1
command: `ls -la /proc/1`
[image]

Start command of the container:

```
docker run -it --name=nessi_centos_test centos:latest bash
```

### But in containers with SLES12 or RHEL7 as Docker hosts:

I **get permission denied** with the same command, as you can see in the above links.
command: `ls -la /proc/1`
[image]

### Additional information:

Relied on [Docker security documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/security/)  the containers by default start with restricted set of Linux kernel capabilities.

One of those capabilities is: CAP_SYS_PTARCE
 
this capability exists by default in any Linux host machine:

Example in Linux machine:
[image]

But in all containers it is missing by default (unless you start the container with --cap-add=sys_ptrace)

Example in Container:
[image]
you can see here that the container have a restricted set of capabilities that not include the sys_ptrace capability.

So if i start the containers with --cap-add=sys_ptrace in RHEL or SLES as Docker hosts, I get the same behavior as I get in the CentOS 7 as a Docker host.


Example:
Docker host: RHEL7
Docker image: centos:latest (same as before )
`Strat command: docker run -it --name=nessi_centos_test5 --cap-add=sys_ptrace centos:latest bash`

[image]
[image]

as you can see here, for getting the same behavior as I get in CentOS 7 I need to start my containers with additional sys_ptrace capability.

### Technical Information:

1. The different CentOS 7 behavior:    Run command in container:
   `ls -la /proc/1`
    results:  no errors
2. The regular behavior of other hosts (RHEL7 and SLES12)  Run command
   in container:
    `ls -la /proc/1`
    results:

`ls: cannot read symbolic link /proc/1/cwd: Permission denied
 ls: cannot read symbolic link /proc/1/root: Permission denied
 ls: cannot read symbolic link /proc/1/exe: Permission denied`

1. **The different CentOS 7 behavior reproduced in:**

[root@localhost Desktop]# **uname -a**
Linux localhost.localdomain 3.10.0-327.22.2.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Jun 23 17:05:11 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

[root@localhost Desktop]# **docker info**
Containers: 1
 Running: 0
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 1
Images: 1
Server Version: 1.11.2
Storage Driver: devicemapper
 Pool Name: docker-253:0-136686025-pool
 Pool Blocksize: 65.54 kB
 Base Device Size: 10.74 GB
 Backing Filesystem: xfs
 Data file: /dev/loop0
 Metadata file: /dev/loop1
 Data Space Used: 324.3 MB
 Data Space Total: 107.4 GB
 Data Space Available: 35.43 GB
 Metadata Space Used: 847.9 kB
 Metadata Space Total: 2.147 GB
 Metadata Space Available: 2.147 GB
 Udev Sync Supported: true
 Deferred Removal Enabled: false
 Deferred Deletion Enabled: false
 Deferred Deleted Device Count: 0
 Data loop file: /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/devicemapper/data
 WARNING: Usage of loopback devices is strongly discouraged for production use. 
Either use `--storage-opt dm.thinpooldev` or use `--storage-opt <br>dm.no_warn_on_loop_devices=true` to suppress this warning.
 Metadata loop file: /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/devicemapper/metadata
 Library Version: 1.02.107-RHEL7 (2016-06-09)
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins: 
 Volume: local
 Network: null host bridge
Kernel Version: 3.10.0-327.22.2.el7.x86_64
Operating System: CentOS Linux 7 (Core)
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 1
Total Memory: 993.3 MiB
Name: localhost.localdomain
ID: BPVJ:YDPR:4VUO:WNBN:DVZH:7MEH:TPMP:Y3MP:GMN7:UT36:LQ74:GJ4N
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug mode (client): false
Debug mode (server): false
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
WARNING: bridge-nf-call-iptables is disabled
WARNING: bridge-nf-call-ip6tables is disabled

**Docker images:**
centos:latest
ubuntu:14.04

**Also tested on:**
Docker daemon version : 1.10.2

2. **The regular behavior of other hosts (RHEL7 and SLES12)**

   **RHEL7 as Docker host:**

   [root@localhost ~]# **uname -a**
   Linux localhost.localdomain 3.10.0-123.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Mon May 5 11:16:57 EDT 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

   [root@localhost ~]# **docker info**
   Containers: 14
   Running: 6
   Paused: 0
   Stopped: 8
   Images: 22
   Server Version: 1.11.2
   Storage Driver: devicemapper
   Pool Name: docker-253:0-67168288-pool
   Pool Blocksize: 65.54 kB
   Base Device Size: 10.74 GB
   Backing Filesystem: xfs
   Data file: /dev/loop0
   Metadata file: /dev/loop1
   Data Space Used: 9.66 GB
   Data Space Total: 107.4 GB
   Data Space Available: 16.27 GB
   Metadata Space Used: 7.68 MB
   Metadata Space Total: 2.147 GB
   Metadata Space Available: 2.14 GB
   Udev Sync Supported: true
   Deferred Removal Enabled: false
   Deferred Deletion Enabled: false
   Deferred Deleted Device Count: 0
   Data loop file: /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/devicemapper/data
   WARNING: Usage of loopback devices is strongly discouraged for production use. 
   Either use `--storage-opt dm.thinpooldev` or use `--storage-opt dm.no_warn_on_loop_devices=true` to suppress this warning.
   Metadata loop file: /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/devicemapper/metadata
   Library Version: 1.02.107-RHEL7 (2015-12-01)
   Logging Driver: json-file
   Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
   Plugins:
   Volume: local
   Network: null host bridge
   Kernel Version: 3.10.0-123.el7.x86_64
   Operating System: Red Hat Enterprise Linux
   OSType: linux
   Architecture: x86_64
   CPUs: 2
   Total Memory: 1.798 GiB
   Name: localhost.localdomain
   ID: VL2V:RUOZ:U55X:OCEQ:MAS6:MXYV:CKUY:WJQY:3KH3:LWPW:LUYH:E3MM
   Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
   Debug mode (client): false
   Debug mode (server): false
   Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
   WARNING: bridge-nf-call-iptables is disabled
   WARNING: bridge-nf-call-ip6tables is disabled


   **Docker images:**
   centos:latest
   centos:7
   ubuntu:14.04
   ubuntu:latest
   rhel:latest
   suse/sles12:latest (the image build on SLES machine and copied to RHEL)

   **Also tested on:**
   Docker daemon version : 1.10.3. 1.9


   **SLES12 as Docker host:**

linux-ojix:~ # **uname -a**
Linux linux-ojix 3.12.28-4-default #1 SMP Thu Sep 25 17:02:34 UTC 2014 (9879bd4) x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

linux-ojix:~ # **docker info**
Containers: 6
 Running: 3
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 3
Images: 10
Server Version: 1.10.3

Storage Driver: btrfs
 Build Version: Btrfs v3.18.2+20150430
 Library Version: 101
Execution Driver: native-0.2
Logging Driver: json-file
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge null host
Kernel Version: 3.12.28-4-default
Operating System: SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 12
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 2
Total Memory: 1.853 GiB
Name: linux-ojix
ID: NU4F:MOFR:RTUA:F2OM:4G67:NMGV:76S6:BONN:ASD5:XGHF:KVJQ:N242
WARNING: No swap limit support


**Docker images:**
centos:latest
centos:7
ubuntu:14.04
ubuntu:latest
suse/sles12:latest 



**Does anyone understand why CentOS as a Docker host causes different container behavior (ls –la /proc/1 in the container - no error) compared to any other host OS (ls –la /proc/1 in the container - with permission denied errors)?**

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved, Thanks a lot :)

The steps to fix the issue (related to RHEL as docker host machine):
1. I installed Docker version: docker-1.10.3-44  from rhel-7-server-extras-rpms
2. Upgraded my kernel from  3.10.0-229.el7.x86_64 to kernel-3.10.0-327.18.2.el7.x86_64.
3. reboot my machine, and now i can resolve the symbolic link under /proc/1 inside the containers.